# fdopen not working

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Having issues getting open and fdopen to work, the code:

```
    LOGI("opened %s", strerror( errno ));
    int handle= open("/mnt/sdcard/license.rar",O_RDONLY);
    LOGI("opened %s", strerror( errno ));
    FILE* hNewFile= fdopen(handle,"r");
    LOGI("opened handle %d hNewFile %d %s",handle, hNewFile, strerror( errno ));
```

Corresponding log file:

```
03-09 14:12:40.151: opened No such file or directory
03-09 14:12:40.160: opened No such file or directory
03-09 14:12:40.160: opened handle 3 hNewFile 0 Invalid argument
```

I do have the correct manifest permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure /mnt/sdcard/ is actually the correct path? Use the Java side API getExternalStorageDirectory() (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory() to make sure. You can then pass that directory to your JNI code. Also, why even do this portion in native at all?

Comment: it is native because i'm actually porting some code to android... and this is where things fail.

Comment: i know this is correct path because i successfully created a file in this directory using the ndk using the simple code:

 FILE* file = fopen("/mnt/sdcard/file.blah","w+");

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        fputs("HELLO WORLD!\n", file);
        fflush(file);
        fclose(file);
}